# Customizer JS API get value of customizer field

Tags: customization, api

I want to use a javascript plugin on my website that should be initialized with values set in the wordpress customizer.

```
Kirki::add_field( 'artist_theme_config', array(
  'type'        => 'select',
  'settings'    => 'gallery_lightgallery_transition',
  'label'       => __( 'Select the transition type of your lightgalleries', 'site-name' ),
  'section'     => 'artist_theme_gallery_style',
  'default'     => 'lg-slide',
  'priority'    => 10,
  'choices'     => array(
    'lg-slide' => esc_attr__( 'Slide', 'site-name' ),
    'lg-fade' => esc_attr__( 'Fade', 'site-name' ),
    'lg-zoom-in' => esc_attr__( 'Zoom In', 'site-name' ),
  ),
) );
```

My goal is to run the initialization logic with the options set in the customizer. Therfore I need to get the value of the setting in a custom javascript. I found that one way (is it correct?) to get the value is:

```
wp.customize.instance( 'gallery_lightgallery_transition' ).get();
```

However that just works if the customizer is open. What is the correct way to get the value of a customizer field in javascript? Do I need to enqueue the script with the correct dependency, like in

```
wp_enqueue_script('sage/customizer_controls.js', asset_path('scripts/customizer_controls.js'), [ 'customize-controls' ], null, true);
```

? I do not want to put the logic in the `customizer_controls.js` however, but in a file called `plugins.js`. There is a long discussion on [how to pass variables from php to javascript in wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript), however there should be a way with the new customizer api I guess, just can't find any examples or documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it the same way you'd get options, shortcodes, or any other WordPress value into JavaScript: You need to get them with PHP and pass them to the script with `wp_localize_script()`:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script', asset_path( 'scripts/plugins.js' ), [], null, true );
wp_localize_script(
    'my-script',
    'myScript',
    [
        'galleryTransition' => get_theme_option( 'gallery_lightgallery_transition' ),
    ]
);
```

Just change `my-script` and `myScript` to something specific to your project.

Now you can access the value in your script via `myScript.galleryTransition`.

Comment: I will check that out, thanks. I thought there would be a way with the new JS customizer API?

Comment: Why would there be? The JS Customizer API is for working with controls inside the Customizer. It's got nothing to do with the front end. Any front-end API for working with the Customizer data would either just be doing what I'm doing in my answer, which would be a waste because most Customizer values wouldn't be needed in JS, or would require an AJAX request, which would be slower.